# NodeJS Express HTTP request 2 minute stall

Tags: node.js, http, express, https

I have a nodeJS server running express and I am making API calls to access a database thats on the server from an angular application.

When I make more then 2 http calls to the localhost server one always gets stalled for 2 minutes. As seen in the picture from chrome dev tools.

I been looking into it and found that chrome cant have more then 6 TCP connections at a time. Am I making the connect to the databse correctly and how can I prevent this 2 minute stall?

[image]

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const sql = require('mssql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var dbConfig = {
    server: 'DATABASESERVER',
    database:'DB1',
    user:'ADMIN',
    password:'WHATEVERPASS',
    port:1600
};

var colorDBConfig = {
  server:'DATABASESERVER',
  database:'DB2',
  user:'ADMIN',
  password:'WHATEVERPASS',
  port:1700
};

var usersDBConfig = {
  server:'DATABASESERVER',
  database:'DB3',
  user:'ADMIN',
  password:'WHATEVERPASS',
  port:1800
};


app.get('/carlist',function(req,res){
  console.log("I have recieved car request");
    sql.close()
    sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .execute('dbo.getCarsJoinColor')
    }).then(result => {
        var carlist = result.recordsets[0];
        res.json(carlist);
        sql.close()
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Oopsy Woopsy that's not right!");
        console.log(err);
        sql.close();
        return err;
    })
});

app.get('/carcolorlist',function(req,res){
    console.log("modal request recieved");
    sql.close()
    sql.connect(colorDBConfig).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .execute('dbo.getColorCarsJoinCars')
    }).then(result => {
        var carColorList = result.recordset;
        res.json(carColorList);
        sql.close()
   }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Oopsy Woopsy that's not right!");
        console.log(err);
        sql.close();
      return err;
   })
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  sql.close()
  sql.connect(usersDBConfig).then(pool => {
    return pool.request()
    .query('SELECT * FROM Users.dbo.Accounts WHERE Name = ' + "'" + req.body.QNumber + "'" + 'AND Password = ' + "'" + req.body.Password + "'")
  }).then(result => {
    var user = result.recordset;
    res.json(user);
    sql.close()
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("Oopsy Woopsy that's not right!");
    console.log(err);
    sql.close();
    return err;
  })
})
```

Comment: i'm guessing it has something to do with u are trying to create multiple connection to the database with same port.

Comment: Change the ports to 1600, 1700 and 1800 and still getting the two minute stall.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the database driver that you are using but why is it that you always `close` the sql connection whenever a request comes in? If there is something ongoing and another request comes in to forcefully terminate it, would that possibly be a problem?

Comment: (ignoring the fact that the database connection should be `singleton`) Is `sql.close()` returning a promise? If yes, you need to reconnect in the resolved promise.

Comment: If I dont use sql.close() I was getting the error Global connection already exists.

Comment: Yeah but ur 2nd request still connect to 1600,1700,1800 right? And 3 rd request and so on. They all try to create connection to same ports. How can you tell the port is available before another request come in and connect to it?

Comment: How should I go about defining the databases so they use diffrent ports?

Comment: well usually  just start the connection when you start node server.conn1, conn2, conn3 and exec query on each of them for each request when you need to , but don't connect and disconnect in each request. make sense ?

Comment: Yes that makes sense.

Comment: @feiiiiii Your explaitnation worked I needed to make a golbal connection for each database I was using then use those connections for each route. This stopped the 2 minute stall problem I was having. If you want to write up the answer I will give you the check.

Comment: its ok, glad you made it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to make global connection then used those global connections for each route.

```
var dbConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
var dbColorConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(colorDBConfig);
var dbUserConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(usersDBConfig);

//Within the route
var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
request.execute('dbo.getUsers').then(function (result) {
res.json(result.recordsets[0]);
dbConn.close();
```